# how to uncheck a group of radio buttons when one in another group is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have 2 groups of radio buttons. When a button in on group is clicked any button in the other group should be unchecked, and vice versa.
I tried below which works only once.
The smartest way I thought would be click(). But I can't get my head around it. Any suggestions?

```
function uncheckRadioBtnSet(){
  if ($('[name="a"]').is(':checked')){
    $('input[name="b"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).off('click');
  }else{
    $('input[name="a"]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).off('click');
  }
}

$("input[name='a']").click(function(){
   uncheckRadioBtnSet();
});
$("input[name='b']").click(function(){
   uncheckRadioBtnSet();
});

<input type="radio" name="a"  value="1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a"  value="3"><br>

<h6> separator </h6>

<input type="radio" name="b" value="4"><br>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="5"><br>
<input type="radio" name="b"  value="6"><br>
```

Comment: Why do they need to be in 2 groups, if they need to show the behavior like a single group?

Comment: thanks, good question. the two groups can't be combined for many reasons on the page. otherwise it would be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$("input[name='a']").click(function(){
   $('input[name="b"]').prop("checked", false);
});
$("input[name='b']").click(function(){
   $('input[name="a"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/xn61vs1q/

Answer (score 1):

Try this `nanocode` :)

```
$("input[name='a'], input[name='b']").click(function(){
   $('input[name="'+{b: 'a',a: 'b'}[this.name]+'"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OXNcSuGVBA1LjOUmL7Vn?p=preview)

---

Updated code according to new requirements

```
$("input[name='item_meta[313]'], input[name='item_meta[314]']").click(function(){
   $('input[name="'+{'item_meta[313]' : 'item_meta[314]', 'item_meta[314]' : 'item_meta[313]'}[this.name]+'"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

However, for the sake of readability, you can also write this code as:

```
var obj = {
  'item_meta[313]' : 'item_meta[314]', 
  'item_meta[314]' : 'item_meta[313]'
}
$("input[name='item_meta[313]'], input[name='item_meta[314]']").click(function(){
   $('input[name="'+obj[this.name]+'"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

[See this updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RJJVmNT4VYzgTfrVbawz?p=preview)

Comment: great nanocode. thanks. it does not seem to work with the name's my buttons have. I can't change them since they are by design like this. names are like this item_meta[313]..

Comment: How many groups of select boxes are there in your actual code? In your question, you've mentioned 2 i.e., 'a' and 'b'

Comment: I've updated the code according to your requirements. Do notify me if it works fine for you.

Comment: looks great, but can't get it work. I get  "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" when putting it into jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}. and without it I get an error with $.

Answer (score 0):

it will be ok if we use same name for all radio buttons

```html
<input type="radio" name="a"  value="1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a"  value="3"><br>
<h6>
separator
</h6>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="4"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="5"><br>
<input type="radio" name="a"  value="6"><br>
```